# C# Why is my datetime always null?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Take a look at the following code:

```
const string UPDATE_TIME_STATUS = "UPDATE BilledHour SET [SubmittedAt] = @SubmittedAt, TimeStatus = 2 WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND WorkDate >= @FromDate AND WorkDate <= @ToDate AND TimeStatus = 1";

using (m_DAL = new DAL())
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(UPDATE_TIME_STATUS, m_DAL.sqlConn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubmittedAt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now; 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", EmployeeID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", EmployeeID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromDate", FromDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToDate", ToDate);

    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

After running this code the database always shows the `[SubmittedAt]` column as null.

```
WorkDate                TimeStatus  SubmittedAt
-----------------------------------------------
2016-12-26 00:00:00.000 2           NULL
2016-12-27 00:00:00.000 2           NULL
2016-12-28 00:00:00.000 2           NULL
2016-12-29 00:00:00.000 2           NULL
2016-12-30 00:00:00.000 2           NULL
```

It's updating the `[TimeStatus]` column, so I know the SQL statement is executing.

Here's the SQL I'm running in Management Studio to review the results:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeID int
DECLARE @SubmittedAt datetime
DECLARE @FromDate datetime
DECLARE @ToDate datetime

SET @EmployeeID = 3111
SET @SubmittedAt = GetDate()
SET @FromDate = '12/25/2016 12:00:00 AM'
SET @ToDate ='12/31/2016 12:00:00 AM'

select WorkDate, TimeStatus, SubmittedAt
from BilledHour
WHERE
    EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
AND
    WorkDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible that your `WHERE` clause return no rows for update.

Comment: Perhaps because SQL Server doesn't recognize your `@SubmittedAt` parameter value as a date. Why are you calling `.ToString()` instead of simply passing `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: You are converting the date to a string. What type is the `SumbittedAt` column?

Comment: Please read [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) where the author discuss the problems with a method that infers the datatype of the parameters from the values passed

Comment: What type of SubmittedAt inDB? Maybe you try write String instead of DateTime (If column has DateTime type in DB).

Comment: Use Profiler to see what SQL is being submitted by your app.

Comment: _cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubmittedAt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now_  it is still a single line but doesn't leave space to any guessing

Comment: As others have eluded to.... *Don't use AddWithValue. It sucks!*

Comment: [SubmittedAt] is a datetime. I've also tried setting the @SubmittedAt parameter to DateTime.Now with the same result.

Comment: Are you sure its updating, as I can see you have not opened the connection yet.

Comment: 'using (m_DAL = new DAL())' opens a connection in the m_DAL instance. I'm using that connection here: 'new SqlCommand(UPDATE_TIME_STATUS, m_DAL.sqlConn)'

Comment: I've amended my code to use `DateTime.Now`. The result is the same.

Comment: Something no one has pointed out, you can just use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the SQL directly, instead of passing `DateTime.Now` as a parameter.  `SET [SubmittedAt] = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Now I've ammended the code again, using `cmd.Parameters.Add(..)` (only for the @SubmittedAt parameter as that is the only parameter that seems not to be working. I've updated my code above.

Comment: Can you show whatever code you're using to retrieve the data after the update? Also, `.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns a value, what value does it return (the `rows` value from your code)? Are you sure it is updating the right rows? *Any* rows?

Comment: Here's the SQL I'm running in Management Studio to review the results:

Comment: Please show us the query that was send to sql server using a profiler

Comment: The real answer had nothing to do with the perceived problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "SubmittedAt" is a DATETIME field in SQL, instead of using this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubmittedAt", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

Use this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubmittedAt", DateTime.Now);
```

or this (as others suggested)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubmittedAt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Also, you mentioned that its updating [TimeStatus] successfully. In your update query, you specified **Update TimeStatus=2 WHERE TimeStatus=1**. Your result set has TimeStatus=1 for all records.

```
WorkDate                TimeStatus  SubmittedAt
2016-12-26 00:00:00.000 1           NULL
2016-12-27 00:00:00.000 1           NULL
2016-12-28 00:00:00.000 1           NULL
2016-12-29 00:00:00.000 1           NULL
2016-12-30 00:00:00.000 1           NULL
```

Are you sure you are looking at the correct data? You might want to search for TimeStatus=2 as below

```
SELECT WorkDate, TimeStatus, SubmittedAt FROM BilledHour Where TimeStatus=2
```

**EDIT 1:**

Work around:

```
const string UPDATE_TIME_STATUS = "UPDATE BilledHour SET [SubmittedAt] = GETDATE(), TimeStatus = 2 WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND WorkDate >= @FromDate AND WorkDate <= @ToDate AND TimeStatus = 1";
```

Skip passing date parameter and just use SQL function GETDATE() in the query.

Comment: My bad. I displayed the results *after* resting them. I'll correct my post.

Comment: I've changed my code to use DateTime.Now. Same result.

Comment: Are you connected to the right database? Sometimes, we might point the code to a different server (DEV, UAT, QA, etc) and will end up verifying in the different database server.

Comment: Well, [TimeStatus] gets updated every time I run the code so I assume so. Also checked the actual connection string so yes.

Comment: Also, please try .Add() method.

Comment: Now I've ammended the code again, using `cmd.Parameters.Add(..)` (only for the @SubmittedAt parameter as that is the only parameter that seems not to be working. I've updated my code above.

Comment: Is there any TRIGGER that is setting the value back to null after an update?

Comment: Nope. I just created this field.

Comment: Did you see the work around? I updated it in my answer.

Comment: Yes I did. Tried it. Still null :(
There has to be something messed up in the prepared SQL. I' gonna run profiler and see whats going on.

Comment: Btw, I run the update in Management Studio and it works just fine.

Comment: @yozepi There has to be some kind of mess up in SQL string (May be a special character?). Can you try using break point and extract the string from the variable, paste it in SSMS and execute it? Also see how many rows are effected (value of rows variable). Also i would suggest to type the whole query again in C# (instead of copy-pasting it).

Comment: One more thing you can do is to remove CONST, bring variable inside USING statement.

Comment: When you are running the code with updated logic, did you roll back the database TimeStatus to 1 before running the code again?

Comment: I do. But it turns code elswhere is setting TimeStatus to 2 before my code ever runs. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I missed the obvious. Before this code is ever run all the `[TimeStatus]` fields are being set to 2. Since the update filters records set to 1 (`AND TimeStatus = 1`) no records get updated.

Now I'm off to find out who is updating my table before I get a chance to...